# Ruby on Rails Render Partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, partial, rails-activerecord

I have a model called Listing that I use to represent a listing for a sublet. I created a model called Filter that I use to filter the sublets based on a form that the user fills out. Upon filling out the form, I want the user to be redirected to a template that has all of the listings that were returned from the filter.

Here is my Filter model.

```
class Filter < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :air_conditioning, :available_rooms, :bathrooms, :furnished, :negotiable, :new, :parking, :maximum_price, :private_bathroom, :show, :term, :total_rooms, :utilities, :washer_dryer
serialize :term

def listings
  @listings ||=find_listings
end

private

def find_listings
  listings=Listing.order(:price)
  listings=Listing.where("listings.price <= ?", maximum_price) if maximum_price.present?
  listings=Listing.where(total_rooms: total_rooms) if total_rooms.present?
  listings=Listing.where(available_rooms: available_rooms) if available_rooms.present?
  listings=Listing.where(bathrooms: bathrooms) if bathrooms.present?
  listings=Listing.where(term: term)
  listings=Listing.where(furnished: furnished)
  listings=Listing.where(negotiable: negotiable)
  listings=Listing.where(utilities: utilities)
  listings=Listing.where(air_conditioning: air_conditioning)
  listings=Listing.where(parking: parking)
  listings=Listing.where(washer_dryer: washer_dryer)
  listings=Listing.where(private_bathroom: private_bathroom)
  listings
  end

end
```

Here is the show method for filter.

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<%= render (@filter.listings)  %>
```

Pretty simple.

And here is the template called _listing.html.erb

```
<div style="padding:5px">
<%= link_to 'New Listing', new_listing_path,{:style=>'', :class => "btn"} %>
<h1>Available Sublets</h1>

<table id="listingTable" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <tr>
    <th><%= link_to 'Filter', new_filter_path,{:style=>'', :class => "btn"} %><%= link_to 'Clear Filter', listings_path, {:style=>'', :class => "btn"} %></th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th><u><%= "Price Per Month" %></u></th>
    <th>Description</th>
  </tr>
<% if @listings !=nil %>
    <% @listings.each do |listing| %>
      <tr onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer';"
      onclick="window.location.href = '<%= url_for(:controller => 'listings', :action => 'show', :id=>listing.id) %>' " >
        <td><%= image_tag listing.photo.url(:small) %></td>
        <td><%= listing.address %></td>
        <td>$<%= listing.price %></td>
        <td width="40%"><%= listing.description %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
<% else if @listings==nil %>
    <p> Sorry, No Sublets Fit Your Criteria! </p>
<% end %>
</table>
```

However, the filter never returns any results... I have tested atleast 20 times with queries that should definitely return atleast 1 listing. I feel like I have a naming convention problem but I have never used partials before. any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code:

```
listings=Listing.where(term: term)
listings=Listing.where(furnished: furnished)
listings=Listing.where(negotiable: negotiable)
listings=Listing.where(utilities: utilities)
listings=Listing.where(air_conditioning: air_conditioning)
listings=Listing.where(parking: parking)
listings=Listing.where(washer_dryer: washer_dryer)
listings=Listing.where(private_bathroom: private_bathroom)
```

Is not actually filtering `listings` down further. Basically, it's reassigning `listings` again and again and again.

If you want to apply successive filters to `listings`, do this:

```
listings = Listing.where(term: term)
listings = listings.where(furnished: furnished)
listings = listings.where(negotiable: negotiable)
...
```

Comment: Thank you, that is true. However, even with that fix, nothing comes up.

Comment: should it be called _listing.html.erb or _listings.html.erb